# Current timestamp is 1 hour behind BST

Tags: php, date, datetime

In the UK we are now in BST and that is GMT+1 and UTC is still at gmt+0.
So when I enter the code below I get the time 2016-04-07 10:48:01, but it should be 2016-04-07 11:48:01.

I've tried changing my php.ini file, which is listed in fig2, and i will put the date from phpinfo() in fig 3

fig1:

```
<?php $current_time = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
echo $current_time ;?>
```

fig2: php.ini

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone =

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

; http://php.net/date.sunset-zenith
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333

date.timezone=Europe/London
```

fig 3: phpinfo();

```
date

date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2015.7
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    UTC
Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   Europe/London   Europe/London
```

Comment: Why are you using `date.timezone = BST` and `date.timezone=Europe/London` in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: date.timezone = BST was mistake was my old php.ini as anyone knows BST doesn't exist i was checking if it would work lol @bruno